# Swagger AWS API Gateway with Strict-Transport-Security

Tags: aws-lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I'm trying to use `Strict-Transport-Security` header with API Gateway on swagger definition, but I keep getting `Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.response.header.Strict-Transport-Security` when I use:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
  responses:
    default:
      statusCode: "200"
      responseParameters:
        method.response.header.Strict-Transport-Security: "'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload'"
```

Full definition below:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title:APIs
  version: 1.0.1
servers:
  - url: "http://localhost:9001"
security:
  - ApiGateway: []
paths:
  /user/{id}:
    get:
      summary: Get user
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: id
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            format: uuid
          description: return user by ID
      responses:
        "200":
          description: user returned successfully
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/User"
        "400":
          description: Validation failure
        "500":
          description: Something went wrong
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri:
          Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${apiLambda.Arn}/invocations
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Strict-Transport-Security: "'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload'"
        passthroughBehavior: "never"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        type: "aws_proxy"

  /user:
    post:
      summary: Create user
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/User"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: User created successfully
        "400":
          description: Validation failure
        "500":
          description: Something went wrong
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri:
          Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${apiLambda.Arn}/invocations
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
        passthroughBehavior: "never"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        type: "aws_proxy"

components:
  securitySchemes:
    ApiGateway:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      required:
        - id
        - name
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          format: uuid
          example: "317d0a1d-1a44-4a47-b2d8-cbe64665591c"
          description: "user ID"
        name:
          type: string
          example: "Josiah Morrow"
          description: "User name"
          minimum: 1
          maximum: 50
```

> Unable to put integration response on 'GET' for resource at path '/user/{id}': Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.response.header.Strict-Transport-Security]